# Issues with except code when using Python smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to create a script to automate sending of emails. I have the base code done and it is all working fine. I am working on error handling to make the experience more user friendly, but I am having issues when using a try/except.

Here is the current function to try/except:

`

```
def send_email():
        try:
            with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
                smtp.login(email_sender, email_password)
                smtp.sendmail(email_sender, email_receiver, send_message.as_string())
                print("Email successfully sent!")
        except smtplib.SMTPResponseException as error:
            error_code = error.smtp_code
            error_message = error.smtp_error
            print("Error code:" + error_code)
            print ("Message:" + error_message)
```

`

The code runs successfully and the email is received. I want to then run some more code based on what the error_code received is.

I am trying to replicate user inputting an incorrect email address format, which should give me the error_code of 553. I can see this in the logs, but none of the code in the except works (I only see the error error in the terminal):

> 

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.11/smtplib.py", line 901, in sendmail
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'ads': (553, b'5.1.3 The recipient address <ads> is not a valid RFC-5321 address.
```

Here I can see that I am successfully receiving the error code 553, but I am not sure why except code is not running, in order for me to access the error received and run more code based on the output?

I tested by changing the except to a basic one, which worked when running the following code:

`

```
except:
            print("ERROR")
```

`

"ERROR" is successfully printed.

I am confused by this as based on the smtplib docs:

> exception smtplib.SMTPResponseException
> Base class for all exceptions that include an SMTP error code. These exceptions are generated in some instances when the SMTP server returns an error code. The error code is stored in the smtp_code attribute of the error, and the smtp_error attribute is set to the error message.

Comment: An `SMTPRecipientsRefused` is not an `SMTPResponseException`.

Comment: Use `smtplib.SMTPException` - It's the lowest class